# how to uniquely identify tags in react

Tags: reactjs, django-taggit

I am trying to access tags on an article using react. At the backend, I implemented tagging functionality using Django-taggit and the tags are returned as an array of strings.

[image]

Then, this is how I have implemented looping through the tags in react

```
<ul className="tags" >
    {!article.tags ? "" : article.tags.map(tag => (

       <Link to="/view-articles">
          <li className="d-inline tag-name" 
              key={tag}
              value={tag}>
              {tag}
          </li>
       </Link>

    ))}
</ul>
```

The problem is, react gives the error `‘Missing "key" prop for element in iterator’`
How do I go about resolving this? It seems I need a unique identifier for each tag for this to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a key prop to Link.You don't need key on the li element.You need it at the topmost element of the JSX that your are repeating in map.Keep in mind that the key prop should be a unique constant.If your tags are unique,then just use the tag value or i prefer to do something like this.
Concatenating the tag and index so that even if the tag repeats,the resulting string will be unique.

```
   article.tags.map((tag,index) => (

       <Link key = {`${tag}-index`} to="/view-articles">
          <li className="d-inline tag-name" 
             value={tag}>
           {tag}
        </li>
   </Link>
```

As a sidenote, {`${tag}-index`} just means {tag + '' + index}.I prefer ES6 template literals to string concatenation.

Comment: disagree on using index there. this way if I put new tag at first position it it would completely recreate the list since no `key` was matched. it's known pitfall of using `index`as a part of `key`. Also I believe there will be no duplicated tags since it does not make sense

Comment: I had a scenario where the list value was repeating and i had to render it anyway.So i had to concatenate it.Incase ,you are sure of not repeating then by all means avoid the index.

Comment: then you may use unique `id`(actually it should be first coming in mind to use with `key`). I can not imagine a case when you can have duplicated values without `id` and still able to distinguish duplicates when say editing one of them

Answer (score 1):

If you look closer at your code, you'll see that the element that is output in the iterator is not the `li` element (on which you've placed `key` property), but the `Link`. Try this:

```js
<ul className="tags" >
    {!article.tags ? "" : article.tags.map(tag => (

       <Link to="/view-articles" key={tag}>
          <li
              className="d-inline tag-name" 
              value={tag}
          >
              {tag}
          </li>
       </Link>

    ))}
</ul>
```